# PHP Cron Job Engine

Tags: php, cron

I was wondering how one would go about building a PHP Cron Job "engine".

Essentially I am building a web app with "modules" which go and retrieve data at set intervals. I want these modules to be separate, but they all need to gather data at the same time (roughly) - some are once a day, others every 15 minutes.

With several popular CMS's, you set up a cron job to hit a file every 5 minutes or so - what you can then do is "register" the cron job in each module rather than having to edit the cron tab every time you install a module.

E.g.

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/cron.php
```

In the module you could then do something like

```
function task() {
    // do some work 
}

$cron->register(task())->daily();
```

Or similar - i'm not quite sure how to achieve it, nor am I sure what to search for!

*Edit: I'm not looking for something that will edit the crontab, I am also trying to avoid an SQL database. I know it won't happen magically and I'm happy to edit a master "file" to "install" a module.*

*Edit 2: I suppose essentially what i'm looking for is like [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) do, but without the database... possible?*

Hope it makes sense...

Comment: I'm not clear: Are you trying to build a cron syntax interpreter, which then relies on an underlying system to 'wake' your task up (like a queue, a bus, or a scheduler)?

Comment: [heyziko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1876622/heyziko) yes, i think you understood me right..? Sort of like a cron "interface" where I can add to the cron in my code, rather than needing to edit the cron file on command line

Comment: I'm convinced that working with a database is the best option. I understand that you want your "module" to be separated, but then you can specify in your constructor or config the data source. (Eg the database connection). Then you are free to create the table from the script.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so to. I don't use a database for anything else so seems silly to make one especially... wonder if I could replicate it in a json file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more thinking, I managed to solve this.

Each module now has a "cron" folder. The files in there represent the frequency of which to run (e.g. `halfHourly.php` or `daily.php`).

I then have a PHP class that gets fired at regular intervals, with the type passed as a parameter (e.g. once a day the file gets fired with a "daily" parameter).

Every hour, the hourly, halfHourly and quaterHourly ones run (using a switch statement you can ripple down).  So on and so fourth. The disadvantage is there are several cron statements but no database is needed!

Example of the code that runs

```
// This is done as a switch, so that some tasks can ripple down
switch ($argv[1]) {

    case 'daily':
        $cron->daily();

    case 'hourly':
        $cron->hourly();

    case 'halfHourly':
        $cron->halfHourly();

    case 'quarterHourly':
        $cron->quarterHourly();
    break;

    default:
        $cron->execute($argv[1]);
}
```

And the actual cron class:

```
/**
 * Cron
 */
class Cron {
    private $modules;

    function __construct() {
        exec('ls -d /path/to/modules/*/cron', $files, $return);
        $this->modules = $files;
    }

    function execute($time) {
        $client = $GLOBALS['client'];

        echo PHP_EOL . "\033[1;32mProcessing the " . $time . " crons" . PHP_EOL;

        foreach($this->modules as $module) {
            $path = $module . '/' . $time . '.php';
            if(file_exists($path)) {
                echo PHP_EOL . "\033[1;34mExecuting module cron: \033[0;36m" . $module . PHP_EOL . "\033[0m";
                include $path;
            }
        }
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $this->execute($name);
    }
}
```